# Intersection of two parametrized/visualized surfaces

Tags: list-manipulation, parametric-functions

```
ClearAll;
vmin = 0; vmax = 2; al = Pi/4; xm = 3.6;
loxoSph = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{xm + Sech[v Cot[al]] Cos[v + t], 
    Sech[v Cot[al]] Sin[v + t], Tanh[v Cot[al]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 
    vmin, vmax}, PlotRange -> All];
bt = 0.15; rm = 1.25; rmin = 2 rm; rmax = 3.6 rm; zmin = 0; zmax = 1;
plane = ParametricPlot3D[{r, -r Tan[bt], z}, {r, 2 rm, rmax}, {z, 
    zmin, zmax}];
Show[plane, loxoSph]
```

[image: ParaPlaneCutsParaSph]

One of four $(t,v,r,z)$ is chosen as independent parameter with a  uniform increment. Respective $(x,y,z)$ are equated whle solving but gets bit complicated due to simultaneity.

How is a Table solved  for the remaining three coordinates on the line of intersection ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do find and visualize intersection in an ugly  way, e.g.:

```
f[t_, v_] := {3.6` + Cos[t + v] Sech[v], Sech[v] Sin[t + v], Tanh[v]}
g[r_, z_] := {r, -r Tan[bt], z}
sol = Quiet@Solve[f[t, v] == g[r, z], {v, t, r, z}];
int1 = ParametricPlot3D[g @@ ({r, z} /. sol[[10]]), {v, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
int2 = ParametricPlot3D[g @@ ({r, z} /. sol[[11]]), {v, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
surf1 = ParametricPlot3D[f[t, v], {v, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}];
surf2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r, -r Tan[bt], z}, {r, 2.5, 3.6 1.25}, {z, 
    0, 1}, Mesh -> None];
Show[surf1, surf2, int1, int2]
```

[image]

where solution 10 and 11 give the desired octants (it doesn't handle adding constraint).

However, the `loxoSph` is a unit sphere with centre (3.6,0,0).

Solving the equivalent problem centred on (0,0,0) with translated plane yields circle parametrization:

```
h[u_, v_] := g[u, v] - {3.6, 0, 0};
par = v /. Solve[h[u, v].h[u, v] == 1, {u, v}];
func1[p_] := h[p, par[[1]] /. u -> p] + {3.6, 0, 0}
func2[p_] := h[p, par[[2]] /. u -> p] + {3.6, 0, 0}
pp = ParametricPlot3D[func2[t], {t, 2.5, 4.5}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[surf1, surf2, pp]
```

[image]

Comment: I wish to only see a Table of numerical data of points of  intersection with uniform increment of one parameter.

Comment: @Narasimham then simply use  `Table[func2[j],{j, 2.5,4.5,inc}`  above for whatever `inc`rement you desire.